# Knapsack DP with array of hashes

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, decimal

I'm trying to reduce the time and space needed by the Knapsack DP algorithm with non-integer values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Meet-in-the-Middle_Algorithm

```
In particular, if the [elements] are nonnegative but not integers, we could 
still use the dynamic programming algorithm by scaling and rounding (i.e. using 
fixed-point arithmetic), but if the problem requires  fractional digits of 
precision to arrive at the correct answer, W will need to be scaled by 10^d,  
and the DP algorithm will require O(W * 10^d) space and O(nW * 10^d) time.
```

The DP knapsack algorithm uses a [ n x W ] matrix, filling it up with results, but some columns never get filled - they do not match any combination of object weights. This way, they simply end up filled with zeros on each row and just waste time and space.

If we used an array of hashes instead of a matrix, we could reduce the time and space needed.

```
edit:
knapsack capacity = 2
items: [{weight:2,value:3} ]

   [0   1   2]
   [0   0   0] 
2: [0   0   3]
        ^
Do we need this column?

Substitution with hash:
2: {0:0, 2:3}
```

In Python, dict insertion has a O(n) worse case and an O(1) "amortized" linear time.

Am I missing something?

What would be the complexity of such a variation on the knapsack DP algorithm ?

Comment: I don't follow. How are you trying to change it? What will be the keys/values of your dictionary?

Comment: The hashes would substitute the "rows" of the matrix. The keys would be weights, the values would be the subset sums

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to save? the "rows" still needs the same number of elements (weights). If you have a different idea regarding it - we will gladly hear it.

Comment: Here's an example. Knapsack capacity 2, items: {weight:2, value:3}. The solution is trivial, take the only item that there is. Do we really need the column representing weight "1" ?

Comment: For this to have lower complexity there would have to be an upper limit on the number of "needed" rows compared to total rows. However, the upper limit is equal to the number of total rows - it is possible for all rows to be needed, so this obviously does not result in lower complexity. In the general case we have to assume most rows are filled, for example: capacity 1000, items = {2, 3}

Comment: Let's assume it's a 0-1 knapsack, so we have no repetitions. capacity 1000, items[2,3], 997 columns not needed

Comment: How does being 0-1 change it? capacity = 1000, items = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512}. Only 10 items, no repetitions, yet all 1000 rows are filled. Favorable cases are meaningless when talking about complexity.

Comment: Mhm, you must be right. Thank you! I'd vote you if post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you speak of is, if I can say that, happy cases - cases in which you have very little number of items to insert in a knapsack with huge volume. In this case hashmap can prove to be optimization triggering the complexity from `O(W * n)` to just `O(min(O(2^n * n), O(W * n)))` (`2^n` is the number of combination of the n elements). However, with this estimation it is obvious that for not that big number of elements, the `O(2^n * n)` will dominate the other estimation. Also, note that whilst the `O(W * n)` are of the same class, the constant in the latter case is significantly greater (and even more: the estimation in the second case considers amortized complexity, not worst case).

Thus you get that in certain cases the hash map might prove to be better, but in the common case the opposite holds true.

Comment: I think you are giving the same "n" name to different things. Hash insertion may be O(n) on the valid columns - the ones which represent the number of subsets available. Not directly related to O(W), which is the capacity of the knapsack. The average complexity would then be O(n*m) with a O(n*m^2) worst case?

Comment: @lordkrandel: I am sorry for my first answer, it got even me puzzled as I read it 3 hours later. I rephrased it now. Hopefully it will be of some help.